# Set that is compact on $\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Topology Without Tears and came across what is probably a fundamental theorem for compactness: "Let $(X,T)$ be any topological space and $A=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_n\}$ any finite subset of $(X,T)$. Then $A$ is compact" (pg 171).

Is it then fair to say that if consider $\mathbb{Z}$ with the digital line topology that the sets $\{4, 5, 6, ...\}$ and $\{..., –9, –8, –7\}$ are not compact as they are an infinite subset of $(X,T)$?

Comment: I don't know what the digital line topology is but note that your book gives an "if...then" statement, and it is *definitely not* an "if and only if" statement, so you cannot conclude that a set is not compact, solely because it is infinite.

Comment: Although finite sets are always compact, it's not true in general that infinite sets are non-compact; some infinite sets are compact. In this particular case, the two infinite sets you mentioned are not compact in the digital line topology.

Comment: To say that a finite topology, such as $A$, is compact is a very simple statement: not only does every open cover of $A$ have a finite subcover, every open cover of $A$ is *already finite*, because there are only finitely many subsets of $A$.

Comment: @lee The digital line topology is not finite.

Comment: I was referring to the finite subset $A$. Edited my comment to be clear.

Comment: You say "a finite topology, such as $A$", but I think $A$ is not intended to be a topology. Perhaps you meant "a finite subspace, such as $A$"?

Answer (score 2):

It is true that any finite set, in any topological space, is compact. The converse, however, is **false**: you don't need to be finite to be compact. For instance, the interval $[0, 1]$ is compact in the real line with the usual topology (see the Heine-Borel theorem), but is of course infinite.

While the sets you describe are indeed non-compact, the *reason* you've given - that they're infinite - is insufficient.